# How to go to a fragment method from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I have four classes:

1. FragmentActivity
2. FragmentPagerAdapter
3. FragmentA
4. FragmentB

In FragmentActivity I set the TabPagerAdapter (FragmentPagerAdapter) to ViewPager.

```
viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
tabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(this, viewPager);
viewPager.setAdapter(tabAbAdapter);
```

In the TabPagerAdapter I return the two Fragments in getItem() from a switch statement

```
return new fragmentA();
return new fragmentB();
```

Fragment A searches and passes a variable to the FragmentActivity via an interface method.

```
public void onDataPass(String data) {
    kks= data;
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

All of this works fine. I get the data from a list in FragmentA and it gets passed back to MainActivity. The setCurrentItem(1) displays Fragment B.

The part that I am stuck on is how I can run FragmentB.upDateEquipment(kks)  between kks = data and viewPager.SetCurrentItem() in onDataPass.

I can get the value of kks from Fragment B and run upDateEquipment by implementing setOnClickItemListener from a button in Fragment B and this works but I would prefer not to have to add the extra click for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Fragment fr = ((ActionBarActivity) activity)
                            .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                                    "add_product");

                    if (fr instanceof Sellers_Add_Product_Fragment) {

                        ((Sellers_Add_Product_Fragment) fr).yourMethod();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend getting the fragments from the pager adapter.

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private FragmentA mFragmentA = new FragmentA();
    private FragmentA mFragmentB = new FragmentB();
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return mFragmentA;
            case 1:
                return mFragmentB;
        }
    }

    public ReflashStatusFragment getFragmentA() {
        return mFragmentA;
    }

    public RemoteFlashFragment getFragmentB() {
        return mFragmentB;
    }
```

Then just use something like `mPagerAdapter.getFragmentB.updateEquipment(kks);`

Answer (score 0):

Both the earlier responses possibly would work. But I wanted to add updating FragmentB from the onDataPass method. The issue I was having was getting the instance of FragmentB in order to call the updateEquipment method. I was not getting the correct id in the findFragmentByTag call. Here is the way that I finally gotit to work.

```
onDataPass(String data) {
    kks = data;
    String name - tabAdapter.makeFragmentName(viewPager.getId(), 1);
    FragmentB fragmentB = FragmentB)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(name);
    fragmentB.updateEquipment(kks);
}
```